# How to ask for batch file user input with a timeout

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, timer, shutdown, restart

So I am trying to add a timer to one of my if statements under a set command but I'm not sure what the command would be.  The script will launch and wait thirty minutes before it reboots the PC or wait for a users input to input it at that time or cancel it.  So I have my two if statements for the "restart now" and "cancel" set but now I need an if statement to have it count down from thirty minutes before it executes my restart command.  Also if anyone knows how to add a visual timer on there showing how much time is left that would be a plus.  Thanks guys!!!

```
@Echo off

:START

set /p answer=PC WILL RESTART IN 30 MINUTES, PRESS N TO RESTART NOW OR C TO CANCEL

if "%answer%"=="n" (GOTO Label1)
if "%answer%"=="c" (GOTO Label2)
if "TIMER GOES HERE" "==" (GOTO Label1)

:Label1

shutdown -r -t 60 -f

:Label2 

exit
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar one for hibernate.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (600 -1 1) do (
  set /a "min=%%N/60, sec=%%N%%60, n-=1"
  if !sec! lss 10 set sec=0!sec!
  cls
  choice /c:CN1 /n /m "HIBERNATE in !min!:!sec! - Press N to hibernate Now, or C to Cancel. " /t:1 /d:1
  if not errorlevel 3 goto :break
)
cls
echo HIBERNATE in 0:00 - Press N to hibernate Now, or C to Cancel.
:break
if errorlevel 2 (%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate) else echo Hibernate Canceled
```

Comment: Can you explain how it works? Cool countdown by the way.

Comment: @workoverflow for loop counting down from 600 seconds, -1 at a time until 1. Calculate min and second from seconds. Just pad with 0 for seconds. min and sec is passed to choice string. `/c:CN1` is mapping C and N characters from input to `errorlevel`. If errorlevel is 1 or 2, user pressed a key and jumps to break. errorlevel 2 is N so hibernate.

Answer (score 12):

I reccomend using `CHOICE.EXE`, it comes standard with most versions of Windows (with the exception of Windows NT, 2000 and XP, it used to be downloadable from Microsoft's website, but they seem to have overlooked [this](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Services/TechNet/samples/PS/Win98/Reskit/SCRPTING/choice.exe)* one on their ftp site.) and is simple to use.

```
@Echo off
:START
set waitMins=30

echo PC WILL RESTART IN %waitMins% MINUTES: Press N to restart [N]ow or C to [C]ancel
:: Calculate Seconds
set /a waitMins=waitMins*60
:: Choices are n and c, default choice is n, timeout = 1800 seconds
choice /c nc /d n /t %waitMins%

:: [N]ow = 1; [C]ancel = 2
goto Label%errorlevel%

:Label1

shutdown -r -t 60 -f
:: Make sure that the process doesn't fall through to Lable2
goto :eof

:Label2 
exit
```

---

Simply `CHOICE.EXE` works like this...

```
choice
```

...and is the same as...

```
choice /c yn
```

...both will display...

```
[Y,N]?
```

...and both will wait for the user to press a `Y` or `N`.

Choice stores the result in %errorlevel%. Y=1, N=2.

The code I provided takes advantage of the default `/D <choice>` and timeout `/T <seconds>` options.

In example...

```
choice /c yn /d y /t 5
```

...gives the user a choice of Y or N, will wait for 5 seconds then automaticlly select the default choice of Y, resulting in %ERRORLEVEL%==1.

Another example is...

```
choice /c abcdef /m "Make a choice. "
```

...and it displays...

```
Make a choice. [A,B,C,D,E,F]?
```

...and...

```
A = %ERRORLEVEL% = 1
B = %ERRORLEVEL% = 2
C = %ERRORLEVEL% = 3
D = %ERRORLEVEL% = 4
E = %ERRORLEVEL% = 5
F = %ERRORLEVEL% = 6
```

There is no ERRORLEVEL 0.

For more on the use of `choice`, type `CHOICE /?` at the command prompt.

---

***NOTE** The version of `CHOICE.EXE` I provided a link to uses slightly different commands, but provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really simple solution for Vista and Windows 7 that provides the timeout feature, but does not give a visual countdown.

```
@echo off
choice /c:CN /n /m "PC will restart in 30 minutes. Press N to restart Now, or C to Cancel" /t:1800 /d:N
if errorlevel 2 (shutdown -r -t 60 -f) else echo Restart Canceled
```

Here is a more complex solution for Vista and Windows 7 that provides a visual countdown, but it clears the console window each second. Also the timing is probably a bit off.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1800 -1 1) do (
  set /a "min=%%N/60, sec=%%N%%60, n-=1"
  if !sec! lss 10 set sec=0!sec!
  cls
  choice /c:CN1 /n /m "PC will restart in !min!:!sec! - Press N to restart Now, or C to Cancel. " /t:1 /d:1
  if not errorlevel 3 goto :break
)
cls
echo PC will restart in 0:00 - Press N to restart Now, or C to Cancel.
:break
if errorlevel 2 (shutdown -r -t 60 -f) else echo Restart Canceled
```

If you need an XP solution then I think you will either need to download a non-native command line tool that asks for input with a timeout feature, or else switch to VBScript or JScript.

**EDIT**

Both scripts above can be adapted to run on XP by using the [CHOICE.EXE download from the Microsoft FTP site](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/Services/TechNet/samples/PS/Win98/Reskit/SCRPTING/choice.exe) that James K provided in his answer.

That version of CHOICE has slightly different syntax.

To adapt my first script, use:

```
choice /c:CN /n /t:N,1800 "PC will restart in 30 minutes. Press N to restart Now, or C to Cancel"
```

To adapt my second script, use:

```
choice /c:CN1 /n /t:1,1 "PC will restart in !min!:!sec! - Press N to restart Now, or C to Cancel. "
```

**EDIT - Here is a crude VBS solution that is compatible with XP**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
for i = 30 to 1 step -1
  if i=1 then unit=" minute" else unit=" minutes"
  rtn = objShell.Popup ( _
    "The machine would like to Restart."&VbCrLf&VbCrLf& _
    "Click OK to restart now"&VbCrLf& _
    "Click Cancel or the [X] close button to abort the restart"&VbCrLf& _
    "Do nothing and the machine will restart in "&i&unit, _
    60, "Restart in "&i&unit, 1+48 _
  )
  if rtn <> -1 then exit for
next
if rtn <> 2 then objShell.Run "shutdown -r -f"
```

I think you can provide a more elegant VBS solution using HTA, but that is a lot more work, and I don't really know much about that technology.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the choice command?  Most my PC's will be XP machines and I really don't want to go around to all of them and download that choice command from Microsoft.

Comment: @MattP - As I already stated in my answer, you can with VBS, but not with native batch. See my updated answer for a VBS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code to make the script pause for a specified number of milliseconds:

```
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w <milliseconds> >NUL
```

This will send out 1 ping to the IP address `1.1.1.1` after `<milliseconds>` has elapsed. And the output of the `ping` command will be dismissed to NUL.

Comment: How does that help? The OP needs to prompt for user input and automatically use a default value if the user does not respond within a timeout period. The only native batch command to do that is CHOICE, but that is not native to XP.

Comment: They changed their requirements after I answered their original question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this script by SPC_75
its a .vbs file though, and for hibernate, but its easy to modify for sleep or shutdown.

```
'//*******************************************
'//hibernate.vbs
'//Purpose: Count Down to action (Hibernate)
'//Tested on Server 2008, Win 7 64bit, and XP
'//Author: SPC_75 
'//Revision 1.3
'//Date: 1/09/2011
'//*******************************************

Option Explicit
Dim timeout, objShell, intReturn
Const wshOk = 1
Const wshOkDialog = 0
'Const wshIcon = 16 '/critical
'Const wshIcon = 32 '/question
Const wshIcon = 48 '/exclamation
'Const wshIcon = 64 '/information

timeout = 30 '/Timeout in seconds

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  Do Until timeout = 0
    timeout = timeout - 1
    intReturn = objShell.Popup(vbCrlf &"Hibernation about to initiate. Abort?"&vbCrlf & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & "Time until hibernation : " & timeout, 1, "Hibernation", wshOkDialog + wshIcon + 4096)
    If intReturn = wshOk Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
  loop
  objShell.Run "powercfg /hibernate on"
  objShell.Run "shutdown -h"
  objShell.Run "rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate"  '/XP specific Hibernation command
set objShell = nothing

'//EOF
```

Works perfectly with a warning and timeout.