# Command to auto-exit a batch if left idle?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was wondering if there was a command to automatically exit a batch file if it is left alone for a certain number of seconds.

I made a little program similar to the one found [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Some-Cool-Batch-Applications/step4/Site-Selector/). Most of the coding I used is displayed on the page, but it basically asks you what website you want to visit, and selecting one of the options opens a browser window with the desired page. however, after selecting one of the listed sites, the program displays the options to either exit or return to the top. This is where I usually forget about it until I close whatever I was looking at, and the batch is still open in the background.

So is there anyway to set a auto-exit timer without it interrupting the user, and without restricting the ability to go back and select another option?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4340058/548036 answer by @daniel11 could have the answer (TIMEOUT /T 3600 /NOBREAK)

Comment: No you don't want `timeout`, you want `choice`.:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331428/how-to-ask-for-batch-file-user-input-with-a-timeout

Comment: You could also multi-thread and force terminate. But that would be for a complicated task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `choice` command, instead `set /p`

Where **z** is an automatic option, you can use another letter.

**/D** is the default option if time is passed.
**/T** is the time to wait (this case, 5 seconds).

`choice /n /c:zbe /T 5 /D x  /M "Make your selection"`

Then use it on your code:

```
choice /n /c:xbe /T 5 /D x  /M "Make your selection"
if errorlevel 1 exit
if errorlevel 2 goto :option_b
if errorlevel 3 goto :option_e
```

More info type in cmd:
`choice /?`

Comment: hey @Honguito98 nice to see you here.

Comment: I found out through experimentation that the order of the "if errorlevel" statements does matter. After some trial and error, I got it to work beautifully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here

```
set /p udefine=
```

this line is waiting for b or e

Since you only want to exit the batch file after selecting one website, you can just wipe these lines

```
echo Type [e] to exit or [b] to go back and select another site.
echo.
set /p udefine=
echo.
echo ***************************************************************
if %udefine%==b goto top
if %udefine%==e goto exit
:exit
cls
echo ***************************************************************
```

and also this line (before the last one)

```
pause
```